# how to navigate to url with fragment identifier?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I've been searching for the whole day but it seems like I didn't find anything which address my problem, what I want to do is just a simple navigate using these example:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate( new Uri( "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax" ), "_blank" );
```

but all I get on my browser is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme

as you see the fragment identifier is gone, is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: What do you mean? even if you browse the URL you will get the same!

Comment: I want to open a new html page using the code above on a Silverlight app. But on my browser the # (Bookmark) is missing.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me as-is.  What browser are you using? If chrome or IE10 I think they hide stuff in your address bar to look more user-friendly. You have to change some setting.

You can try this too, but either way did the same thing for me.

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(New Uri("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax", UriKind.Absolute), "_blank")
```

*BTW: By work I mean it went to the page and jumped down to that bookmark.*

Comment: Thanks, I tried with Firefox and Chrome and it worked just fine, maybe it's an issue with IE.

Comment: I'm using IE9 with no issue.  Odd

Comment: can you tell me what is your system? Silverlight version? .net framework version?